# WSDL2JAVA can't set extraarg in Maven

Tags: maven, ant, wsdl, migration, wsdl2java

I made a migration from Ant to Maven project and i have problem that pieces me off:

1. In my Ant bild.xml i have following args in wsdl2java tasc:

   ```
       <arg value="-ns2p" />
       <arg value="${wsdl-ns-binding}" />
   ```

   And I want to do the same in my pom.xml. But it's didn't work!! No matter how i try.. 
   What I doing wrong ???
   Here the example of WSDL2Java plugin definition:

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
           <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.6.2</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <packageName>ru.domain.ws.services.persistence.etb.mortgage.axis2.jaxb.server</packageName>
                       <wsdlFile>${wsdl-home}/ETB_MortgagePersistence.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                       <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/generated</outputDirectory>        
                       <flattenFiles>true</flattenFiles>
                       <databindingName>jaxbri</databindingName>
                       <overWrite>true</overWrite> 
               <!--    <namespaceToPackage> 
                           http://ws.domain.ru/persistence/ETB/mortgage/wsdl=ru.domain.ws.services.persistence.etb.mortgage.wsdl
                       </namespaceToPackage> -->

                       <wsdlOptions>
                           <wsdlOption>
                                <extraargs>
                                   <extraarg>-ns2p</extraarg>
                                   <extraarg>http://ws.domain.ru/persistence/ETB/mortgage/wsdl=ru.domain.ws.services.persistence.etb.mortgage.wsdl</extraarg>  
                                </extraargs>                                
                           </wsdlOption>
                       </wsdlOptions>

                       <options>
                           <property>
                               <name>bindingFileName</name>
                               <value>${jaxb-binding-path}</value>
                           </property>
                       </options> 

                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
           <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                   <artifactId>axis2-jaxbri</artifactId>
                   <version>1.6.2</version>
               </dependency>
           </dependencies>
       </plugin>
   ```

${wsdl-ns-binding} variable is http://ws.domain.ru/persistence/ETB/mortgage/wsdl=ru.domain.ws.services.persistence.etb.mortgage.wsdl

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout (specifying the wsdl file inside the wsdlOptions)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${wsdl-home}/ETB_MortgagePersistence.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>  
                            <extraarg>-ns2p</extraarg>  
                            <extraarg>http://ws.domain.ru/persistence/ETB/mortgage/wsdl=ru.domain.ws.services.persistence.etb.mortgage.wsdl</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```